# Running a GUI script - everything freezes

Tags: python, gui, gtk, git

I cloned [this branch](https://github.com/HaseloffLab/CellModeller/tree/python3) from GitHub, created a Python3 environment, activated it, and ran setup.py install. To run the GUI script, I typed `https://github.com/HaseloffLab/CellModeller/tree/python3`. I only needed to install PyQt5. [Here](https://github.com/HaseloffLab/CellModeller/wiki/User-Guide) it shows what it should look like (though the documentation is for the old model in Python2).

I got the following warning:

```
(cellmodeller) me@me-VirtualBox:~/CellModeller$ python Scripts/CellModellerGUI.py
Gtk-Message: 14:32:32.379: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

The window with the graph in 2D opens, and once I try to click 'Load' or anything (as it appears in the picture of the second link) it freezes and I can't do anything, I even need to force quit it. I tried running a script from the examples, it does run, but there is no graph.

Answer (score 0):

Not a python expert, but this seems not to be an Ubuntu-related issue, as the application installs and runs. You should probably start by following the ["highly recommended" installation method](https://github.com/HaseloffLab/CellModeller/wiki/Installation) through Anaconda, and contact the developer/community of CellModeller, instead, if the issue persists.

Comment: The problem is that they just upgraded the whole thing to Python3 and I followed the installation steps that the person who created it told me to. He uses a Mac and didn’t have this problem. I was afraid it might be because of my computer or the VM or how I allocated the disk space (I’m not an expert, it’s the first time I use Ubuntu).

Comment: Unless you're running out of disk space, none of the things you mentioned seems a reasonable issue to me - being this a python script, you should just need the required libraries/dependencies, regardless of the hardware. Trying on some other machine might be a good strategy, if possible.